# Install recent linux version in old computer?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, linux-kernel

I have tried to install several distros and versions of linux (Ubuntu and Lubuntu, from 13 to 14.04, and  Mint 17) without success. Everytime the system blocks while loading the installation.

I can only install previous versions like lubuntu 12.04). Every single time the system updates to a recent kernel the system fails to boot.

I have been searching for a long time now, and it seems that the problem is common to a lot of people but with different causes. Sometimes it's the graphic card, sometimes it's the wireless cards...

I tried to boot the system with apci and apic off, nomodeset, forcepae... No success.

This problem is on a VAIO PCG-7F1M. Intel motherboard, broadcom wifi card.

Can anyone help me to solve this please?

EDIT:I don't get error messages. The system just blocks while loading. It depends on the version I am trying to install, but sometimes it blocks while saying "Loading IRQ #9". I am almost certain that it is a kernel problem and it is related to the compatibility with the system hardware.

Comment: Can you run a liveDVD of the distro?  If so, the problem isn't the kernel.  If the LiveDVD also does not work, try running a distro that has a "safe" mode (I beleieve the Debian distros do, among others).  In this mode, you will get both a verbose listing of progress and problems, and it will try exhaustively to solve hardware problems.  The verbose listing may tell you what is hanging and then you will have something specific to research for a solution.

Comment: One more thought--I did a quick search for that computer and couldn't spot any specs (other than it appears to be very old and everyone and his brother is selling replacement screens).  If it is a 32 bit machine and you are trying to install a 64 bit OS, you will get those kinds of installation problems (won't work).

Comment: I also cannot run a LiveDVD. I tried the compatibility mode, and also tried to disable some things (to try to increase the compatibility), no sucess. I will try to do check exactly where it blocks during the loading process and I will post it tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: Try [puppy linux](http://puppylinux.org/wikka/WhatpuppyLinuxisbestforyou).  They have versions for ancient (>5-6 years old) machines.

Comment: Exactly what versions of those distros are you trying to install?  I've installed Debian 7.4.0 **i386** on computers older than @mcalex 's description of *"ancient"*.

Comment: :-)  perhaps I should've said >>5-6 years old.  One version, [Wary puppy 5.5](http://bkhome.org/blog2/?viewDetailed=00159) "has the same old 2.6.32.59 kernel (configured for uniprocessor i486 CPUs)" - ancient enough for ya?

Comment: 5-6 years old isn't even close to ancient in terms of what will happily run a current Linux system (though you may not be doing it from a LiveDVD/USB, relying instead on alternate install media, which is usually ncurses menu driven).  The wifi  might take some configuration to get working, but shouldn't prevent installation by any means, and even if you have poor GPU support, using standard VESA video modes should at least get you a working console with little headache.  As others have said though, make sure you're using a 32 bit build, as amd64 builds won't run on 32 bit hardware.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work -  becaus of some kernel parameter that are optimized for newer hardware
(I can't remember now what part it was - )

But what works:
Download a 12.10 alternate CD (latest for ubuntu/kubuntu, and then

do-release-upgrade

Or alternatively download the latest Lubuntu alternate cd (14.04)

- this one WILL boot
  (you can install another desktop later)